# Unable to connect to Google Cloud via external IP (Jboss)

Tags: networking, jboss, port, firewall, google-compute-engine

**Google Firewall rules:**

```
custom-allow-25         default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:25                                  test
custom-allow-4447       default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:4447                                test
custom-allow-8080       default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:8080                                test
custom-allow-9443       default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:9443                                test
custom-allow-9999       default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:9999                                test
default-allow-http      default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:80                                  http-server
default-allow-https     default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:443                                 https-server
default-allow-icmp      default  0.0.0.0/0     icmp
default-allow-internal  default  10.128.0.0/9  tcp:0-65535,udp:0-65535,icmp
default-allow-rdp       default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:3389
default-allow-ssh       default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:22
```

**Iptables:**

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4447 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9999 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

**PREROUTING TEST:**

```
    DNAT       tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http to::8080
```

**NETSTAT:**

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9999          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1583/java           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1583/java           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      689/sshd            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      824/master          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4447          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1583/java           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9443          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1583/java           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      689/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      824/master          
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      710/mysqld
```

When I do curl localhost:8080 everything works, but when I do

```
curl externalIP:8080
^C - hangs
curl externalIP:80
curl: (7) Failed to connect to XXXXXX port 80: No route to host
```

I can SSH to external IP without problem, Firewall rules in GCE are set to "ANY".

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

EDIT:

Ive also enabled any address in jboss, so it listens on 0.0.0.0 - to no avail.

Comment: Maybe its not listening on the right interface? Just localhost... I'm receving connections, case I can see them in tcpdump

Answer (score 0):

Apparently when you create new rules in google firewall, they arent working right away. Today Ive tried it, didnt change anything and it worked like charm.